# Why is my factory not recognizing my pool association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

we defined the following model

```
  class UserPool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pool
    belongs_to :user
    validates :pool, presence: true
    validates :user, presence: true

    def self.created(date)
      where("DATE(created_at) = ?", date)
    end
  end
```

and the following Factroy

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user_pool do
      pool
      user

      factory :paid_user_pool do
        money_on_pool 10
      end
    end
  end
```

When I run the following test I recive an error

```
  describe "obtain users_pools created at specifict time" do
    before do
      users = create_list :user, 3, active: false
      user4 = create :user

      @pool = create :pool
      users.each do |user|
        create :user_pool, user: user, pool: @pool, created_at: 1.days.ago
      end
      create :user_pool, user: user4, pool: @pool
    end

    it "should return just users_pools created at specifict time" do
      users_pools = @pool.user_pools.created( 1.days.ago )
      users_pools.count.should eq 3
    end
  end
```

Error:

```
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    The validation failed: Pool can’t be blank
```

Why is my factory not recognizing my pool association?

Comment: Please look at my answer and let me know if that solves your problem. If not, show your full error log.

Comment: To clarify, you do have a `Pool` class, right?

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Any other details you need to provide?

Comment: @HunterStevens Yes but I realize that my error was on my model associations not in the factory, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @kentverger you are welcome. Feel free to post your solution as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a factory, you list the attributes with predefined values. Otherwise, you can omit them from the factory and explicitly state it in the test (during create).

```
# Example for :user
factory :user do
  sequence(:name)    { |n| "Test User #{n}" }
end
```

Now, when you call `create(:user)`, the default name will include a number that increases by 1 for every user created. See [`#sequence`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/FactoryGirl/DefinitionProxy#sequence-instance_method) and ["Sequences"](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Sequences) for more information.

Now onto your specific example. You can create the `user_pool` factory one of two ways.

```
# No default attributes, requires explicit assignment
factory :user_pool do
end
create(:user_pool, user: user, pool: @pool)

# Default attributes can be overridden during test
# Requires you to create :user and :pool factories
factory :user_pool do
  after(:build) do |user_pool|
    user_pool.user = create(:user)
    user_pool.pool = create(:pool)
  end
end
```

When you `build` an ActiveRecord object, it is not committed to the database. You are allowed to leave out required attributes. After building the object, two are created (`user`, `pool`), and assigned to the correct `user_pool` attributes. See ["Callbacks"](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks) in the docs for more information.

If you want to create `@pool` in your test, you can still do the following. It will override the default `pool` and `user` attributes.

```
user_pool = create(:user_pool, user: user, pool: @pool)
```